# Asymptotic for Ramanujan's $\tau$-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, elliptic-functions

The Ramanujan's $\tau$-function is defined by
$$q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^{24}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau (n)q^n$$
where $|q|\lt 1$.

Is there a known asymptotic formula for $\tau (n)$ or $|\tau (n)|$, i.e. $\tau (n)\sim f(n)$ where $f$ is some "simple" function?

**Context**

The partition function $p$, defined by
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-q^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)q^n$$
has a known asymptotic formula, namely
$$p (n)\sim\frac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}}\exp\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{2n}{3}}\right);$$
a proof of this uses elliptic/modular function theory.
It was quite shocking for me to observe that no asymptotic formula for $\tau (n)$ appears in the OEIS, but it is maybe hiding somewhere. The changes of signs of $\tau$ appear quite chaotic; still, one would wish to find an asymptotic formula for $|\tau (n)|$. We know that
$$|\tau (n)|=O(n^{\frac{11}{2}+\epsilon})$$
and
$$|\tau (p)|\le 2p^{\frac{11}{2}}$$
if $p$ is prime.
According to Zagier,

> The proof of these formulas, if written out from scratch, has been estimated at 2000 pages.

and in his book Manin cites this as a probable record for the ratio: "length of proof:length of statement" in the whole of mathematics.

Comment: Let me just add that the question of whether there is a positive integer $n$ so that $\tau(n) = 0$ is open.

Comment: Note that even the coefficients of $\prod_n (1-q^n)$, although they (unlike $\tau(n)$) admit an independent description, don't really have an asymptotic formula. Instead they just mostly take the value $0 $ with a few $1$s and $-1$s scattered in.

Comment: The Wikipedia article contains a reference to Nieburs formula breaking down the tau function in terms of divisor functions and polynomials: $$ \tau(n) = n^4 \sigma(n) - 24 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2(35i^2-52in+18n^2)\sigma(i)\sigma(n-i)$$ see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function

Comment: Not really relevant, but: I don't know which book the quote of Manin comes from, claiming Deligne's proof of Ramanujan's conjecture as a record for "length of proof / length of statement", but it is clearly utterly out-of-date by now. For instance the proof of Fermat's last theorem, or the Nikolov-Segal theorem in group theory (which is relatively short to state but whose proof uses the classification of finite simple groups), or Hales on Kepler's conjecture ... all of these are vastly more involved and lengthy proofs than Ramanujan.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Of course; that statement comes from the OEIS and it might be outdated/incorrect. But it's just a note, not really relevant to the question, so I think I'm going to leave the post as it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While an asymptotic for $|\tau(n)|$ does not exist, there are many results that help us to nail down the order of $|\tau(n)|$.  First, let us write
$$\tau(n)=n^{\frac{11}{2}}f(n).$$
Also, let $d(n)$ denote the number of divisors of $n$.  By Deligne's bound and the classical bound for the maximal order of $d(n)$, there exists a constant $c_1>0$ such that

$$|f(n)|\leq d(n)\leq \exp\Big(c_1 \frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\Big)\ll_{\varepsilon}n^{\varepsilon}.$$

1. There exists a density one subset of the positive integers such that
   $$|f(n)|\leq (\log n)^{-\frac{1}{2}+o(1)}.$$
   This was proved by [Luca, Radziwill, and Shparlinski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6606v2).
2. The constant $-\frac{1}{2}$ in the log exponent in the preceding item cannot be improved on a density one subset of the positive integers.  This follows from the central limit theorem of [Luca, Radziwill, and Shparlinski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6606v2).  In particular, if $v\in\mathbb{R}$, then
   $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\#\left\{n\leq x\colon \tau(n)\neq 0,~\displaystyle\frac{\log|f(n)|+\frac{1}{2}\log\log n}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{12})\log\log n}}\geq v\right\}}{\#\{n\leq x\colon \tau(n)\neq 0\}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_v^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt.$$
3. [M. Ram Murty](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01456059) proved that as a consequence of the (now proved) Sato-Tate conjecture, there exists a constant $c_2\in(0,c_1)$ such that
   $$f(n)=\Omega_{\pm}\Big(\exp\Big(c_2\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\Big)\Big).$$
   In light of the remarks above, we see that this is sharp up to the quality of $c_2$.

Items 1 and 3 together show that $|\tau(n)|$ has no asymptotic.

4. For $\tau(p)=f(p)p^{11/2}$ along the primes, we have $|f(p)|\leq 2$ (Deligne), and the (now proven) Sato-Tate conjecture implies that if $I\subseteq[-1,1]$ is a fixed subinterval, then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\#\{p\leq x\colon f(p)/2\in I\}}{\#\{p\leq x\}}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{I}\sqrt{1-t^2}dt.$$

Comment: How can you formalize the statement "$|\tau (n)|$ has no asymptotic"? I would like to know what you mean by that... as there exists $g$ such that $|\tau (n)|\sim g(n)$, take for example $g(n)=|\tau (n)|+\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @Nomas2 Call a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ "eventually continuous" if there exists $x_0 = x_0(g)\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ is continuous on the open interval $(x_0,\infty)$.  Call a function "elementary" if it is built from taking finitely many sums, products, roots and compositions of finitely many polynomial, rational, trigonometric, hyperbolic, and exponential functions, including possibly their inverse functions (cont'd)

Comment: @Nomas2 (cont'd) (1) and (3) show that for all eventually continuous elementary functions $g$, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \tau(n) / (n^{11/2} g(n)) \neq 1$.

Comment: Thanks! Just one last thing: what is $\Omega_+$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations

Answer (score 9):

No, $\tau(n)$ fluctuates wildly, and it cannot be described in simpler terms. It is "irreducible arithmetic data", and we just love that. Same for its absolute value.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to complement the other answers to mention a couple facts about the erratic nature of the signs of $\tau(n)$.  One result is the result of Wilton saying that
$$ \sum_{n \leq N} \frac{\tau(n)}{n^{11/2}} e(\alpha n)  \ll N^{1/2+\varepsilon},$$
with uniformity in $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.  This implies that the $\tau$ function changes sign on any arithmetic progression.

Another result is that $\tau(n)$ tends to have its sign pointing in the same direction as $\cos(2 \pi \sqrt{n})$.  For this result, let $w$ be a fixed smooth compactly supported function.  Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} w(n/N) e(2 \sqrt{n}) \frac{\tau(n)}{n^{11/2}} \sim c N^{3/4},
$$
for some $c \neq 0$.  As far as I know, this was first proved by Iwaniec, Luo, and Sarnak (Low lying zeros of families of $L$-functions.)

Both of the above results generalize to other holomorphic modular forms and Maass forms.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too familiar with this stuff but it seems highly unlikely Ramanujan's tau function would have general asymptotics due to its arithmetic functional quality. Though you could probably find some limit inferior and limit superior which it oscillates around as the input increases since we get: $$\tau(n)=n^4\sigma(n)-24\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2(35i^2-52in+18n^2)\sigma(i)\sigma(n-i)$$ Thus I see that RHS approximating some polynomial times some power of a logarithm times probably some insanely demented divisor-like function which doesn't asymptote to anything.

Comment: Note that identities like the one in your post are pretty useless for analytic purposes. In particular, they do not reveal that $\tau(p)/p^{11/2}$ for prime values of $p$ fluctuates between $-2$ and $+2$. They also do not reveal that $\tau(n)$ is a multiplicative function and in fact satisfies the Hecke multiplicativity relation.

Comment: The idea of studying the lim sup is interesting (no idea if it's been done in the literature before) but, as GH from MO suggests, certainly it's not possible to do with this formula. Instead one can use the multiplicativity - I think it might be possible to prove from this that the lim sup is something like $n^{11/2} e^{ (c+o(1))\log n/\log \log n}$ for an explicit constant $c$ (and the lim inf is the same with a minus sign in front).